# Multiple User ID, Status and Date Lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have an excel sheet that looks like this.

```
User ID Status  Date
A   Open    1/1/2019
A   Filled  1/2/2019
B   Open    1/12/2019
B   Filled  1/15/2019
C   Open    1/22/2019
C   Filled  1/31/2019
D   Open    7/13/2002
E   Open    8/14/2017
E   Filled  9/15/2018
```

I need a code to get this output.

```
UserID Open Filled
A       
B       
C       
D       
E
```

In this case Column D will have  a blank Filled Date since it doesn't have a Filled status in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

[image]

Formula in `G2`:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$10,MATCH($F2,$A$2:$A$10,0))
```

Formula in `H2`:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($A$2:$A$10=$F2),$C$2:$C$10)
```

Drag both down...

Comment: But H5 should be blank since it has no filled status

Comment: You can wrap it in a rather simple `IF` statement to check with `COUNTIF()` if there are more than one occurence of the column F value. If so, then do the lookup.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2010+, you can use Power Query to Pivot on the Status column, with no aggregation.

All of the steps can be done from the GUI, but here is the M-Code for reference:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"User ID", type text}, {"Status", type text}, {"Date", type date}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Status]), "Status", "Date")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions for you here. Both methods are using **array formula**. One is using a combination of **MAX** and **IF** functions, and the other is using a combination of **INDEX** and **MATCH** functions. While the formulas look different, they implied the same logic:

> Find the corresponding location of the date in Column C by finding the location of User ID and Status in Column A and B first.

Please see below for clarifications, and note that the date format in my example is **dd/mm/yyyy**, and I have set the following names in my example:

Name Column A as **User_ID**

Name Column B as **Status**

Name Column C as **Date**

**Method 1**
[image: Method 1]

Here is the formula for Method 1, and you need to press **CSE** (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) to make it work:

```
{=IF(MAX(IF(User_ID&Status=$F2&G$1,Date,0))=0,"",MAX(IF(User_ID&Status=$F2&G$1,Date,0)))}
```

**Method 2**
[image: Method 2]

Here is the formula for Method 2, and you also need to press **CSE** to make it work:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Date,MATCH($F2&G$1,User_ID&Status,0)),"")}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Cheers :)